# Why do i can't make multiple partitions in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: partitioning

I don't know how to make multiple partitions in ubuntu i have watch some tutorials in Youtube but all need a ubuntu boot disk which i don't have is threre any other way to create partitions in ubuntu like windows

Comment: Do you have a single big partition with Ubuntu in it, and want to break it into smaller ones?

Comment: Tell us more about your system. Is it BIOS or UEFI boot? Does it have a Windows or Linux OS on it? Do you have internet? Do you have a USB drive >4GB. Do you have friends with a computer? Is it a laptop or desktop? Is there any unused space on the HDD?

Comment: You can only edit or change unmounted partitions. So need to use Ubuntu live installer which has gparted or a gparted ISO converted to a live boot flash drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition  & https://gparted.org/documentation.php

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04 you can do the following,

Open the Gnome Dash. its the icon on the corner of your screen. with 9 dots on it.

search for disks

it will bring up a gui in which you can select your hardware to create partitions on.

once you have the hardware selected you can use the + button to add partitions and put them how you want them there.

** there must be enough free space on drive in order to create a new partition.

You can resize a partition but I wouldn't recommend that unless you know what your doing. or your data is backed up.